# Heegaard Splitting of Brieskorn homology 3-spheres

Tags: manifolds, geometric-topology, low-dimensional-topology

For pairwise coprime integers $(p,q,r)$, we define a Brieskorn homology 3-spheres by 
$\Sigma(p,q,r)=\{(z_1,z_2,z_3)\in\mathbb{C}^3 | z_1^p+z_2^q+z_3^r=0, |z_1|^2+|z_2|^2+|z_3|^2=1\}$.

I want to know any explicit Heegaard diagram of $\Sigma(p,q,r)$.

What I can find is Heegaard diagram of Szabo's lecture note ([Diagram 2.7](http://www.math.princeton.edu/~szabo/clay.pdf)).

Are there any more?

Comment: Since any other Heegaard diagram can be obtained from this one by isotopy, handle slides and stabilization, you can draw many examples using those moves on the given diagram.